# How do I change the number of ticks in matlab histogram and change axis numbers font size

Tags: matlab, histogram

I only want

- the `x-axis` to display  1 2 3 4 5 6
- the `y-axis` to display 0 20 40 60 80 100
- change the numbers font size to 14

I've tried by setting different axis `property` (ref. to the commented lines of code in the script below) however none of them affect the graph.

```
%Code to generate the diceSum

DiceSum = myDiceRoller(1,500);
figure(1)

%Create the histogram

hist(DiceSum,NDice*6)

%Label the axes

xlabel('Value of Roll','FontSize',16)

ylabel('Number of Times Rolled','FontSize',16)

%set(gca,'X','FontSize',14)

%set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'0' ;'100'})

%set('xtick','FontSize',14)

%set('Xlim',[0,6], 'Ylim',[0 ,100])

%set('xtick',[0:1:6],'ytick',[0:20:100])

%set(gca,'XLim',[0 6])

%set(gca,'XTick',[0 1 2 3 4 5 6])

%set(gca,'XTickLabel',str2mat{'0','1','2','3','4','5','6')

%xlim([0 6])
```

This is a separate function I'm using to create the data and the histogram

```
function [DiceSum] = myDiceRoller(NDice,NRolls)

DiceSum = zeros(1,NRolls);%

for i = 1:NRolls;% on roll 1...roll 2

    for j = 1:NDice;% on roll 1 , roll #s of die

        n = ceil(rand(1)*6);

        DiceSum(1,i) = DiceSum(1,i) + n;

    end

    hist(DiceSum,NDice*6)

    xlabel('Value of Roll')

    ylabel('Number of Times Rolled')

end
```

Comment: That should work.  Where's the rest of your code to generate the graph?

Comment: Its in a different script.

Comment: Put the actual code. Not an image.

Comment: Could it be possible I didn't call the script creating the data correctly? @rayryeng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the `x-axis` displaying  `1 2 3 4 5 6` you have to two possibilities:

- to change the way you call the `hist` function as follows:

  `% hist(DiceSum,1:NDice*6)`

  `hist(DiceSum,1:6)`

this because in the call to `hist` with 2 parameters, the second one should be a vector, in that case, `hist` *returns the distribution of Y among length(x) bins with centers specified by x (being `x` the second parameter) - `R2012b hist help`*

- to directly set the x-axis `xtick` as follows:

  `set(gca,'xtick',[0:6])`

To have the `y-axis` displaying `0 20 40 60 80 100` you have to set the y-axis `ytick` as follows:

```
 set(gca,'ytick',[0:20:100])
```

To change the `x` and `y` axis tick font size to 14 you have to set the axis `fontsize` as follows:

```
set(gca,'FontSize',14)
```

Hope this helps.